# .PHONY in linux kernel Makefile

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu-make

I learn Makefile from Linux kernel.In the file `/scripts/Makefile.build`,it starts with

```
PHONY := __build
__build:
#Init all relevant variables
obj-y :=
obj-m :=
lib-y :=
...
```

on the second line,`__build` doesn't have a dependency.In the latter part of the file,`__build` has a dependency like this:

```
__build: $(if $(KBUILD_BUILTIN),$(builtin-target) $(lib-target) $(extra-y)) \
     $(if $(KBUILD_MODULES),$(obj-m) $(modorder-target)) \
     $(subdir-ym) $(always)
    @:
```

What does the second line which seems senseless mean?A fixed format?

Comment: In a `make` rule tab-indented lines after the `target: prerequisites` line (always one logical line, possibly using line continuation as in your example) are _command lines_ that are passed to a shell for execution when the target needs to be built. `@` at the beginning of a commandline means not to echo it, and in 'standard' (Bourne-family and POSIX) shells `:` is a special command that does nothing. Thus this rule says to not do anything to build the target `__build`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is that make always builds the first explicit target it finds in the makefile, unless you request a different target on the command line.

Putting this statement of the `__build` target up at the top of the makefile may be an attempt to ensure that if you run `make` with no other arguments, it will try to build the `__build` target regardless of what other targets might be defined before the "real" definition of `__build` below.